# Excel Sumifs with added criterias IF a condition is met

Tags: excel, if-statement, sumifs

I wish to do a SUMIFS that adds range & criteria based on certain conditions. The logic is as follow

```
SUMIFS sum_range,
range1, criteria1,
range2, criteria2,
range3, criteria3,
IF(condition1)
    IF(condition2)
        (nothing we're done)
    ELSE
        range4, criteria4
ELSE
    IF(condition 2)
        range5, criteria5
    ELSE
        range4, criteria4
        range5, criteria5
```

So that my sumifs would extend as needed, from 3 ranges to 5 ranges if needed.

Comment: `IF(condition1, SUMIFS(range1...range3),IF(condition2, SUMIFS(range1...range5),"neither condition met"))`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld sounds like an asnwer :)

Comment: It's missing one case, and it would make the formula quite long, repeating every time the 3 first ranges and criterias. Isn't there a better option that adds criterias on certain conditions?

Comment: @Jonathan You might be able to craft a `SUMPRODUCT` solution. Suggest you give it a try, and then edit your question to show your results, as well as some sample data (in **TEXT** form, not pictures).

Comment: @Jonathan "It's missing one case," <--- mind to share your 'complete' solution/code?